# clearInterval issue cause of undefined variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code (that is inside a `button.click()` function)

```
if(inBreak === true) {
      inBreak = false;
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if(seconds == 0) {
          console.log(minutes);
          minutes -= 1;
          seconds = 59;
        } else {
          seconds -= 1;
        }
        $('.minutes').text(minutes);
        $('.seconds').text(seconds);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      inBreak = true;
      console.log(timer);
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
```

The problem is `clearInterval(timer)` not working because timer isn't defined, but I defined it the first time I clicked (and used the function).

So do you have an idea for accomplish that ?
I tried let / const instead var but not working anyway :(s

Comment: what do the `console.log(timer);` output ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: timer is only declared if inBreak is true, but cleared in the else condition so timer doesn't exist in the else condition. define timer where both conditions can access it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`timer` is a local variable, it is destructed at the end of the function.

Store it somewhere else (as a global variable for instance) :

```
window.myTimer = setInterval(function() {
....

clearInterval(window.myTimer);
```

Comment: THanks you my buddy

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are declaring the `timer` variable inside the `click` handler and because of which on every `click`, variable `timer` is **reset**.

e.g.

```
function() { // event handler function
    var timer;
    if(inBreak === true) {
       // code
       timer = setInterval()
    } else {
        // code 
        console.log(timer);
    }
}
```

You should create a variable outside the event handler scope so that it is available and share same reference.

e.g.

```
var timer; // <- Move the declaration outside the function scope to be available and share same reference.
function() { // event handler function
    if(inBreak === true) {
       // code
       timer = setInterval()
    } else {
        // code 
        console.log(timer);
    }
}
```